# TypeScript - How to properly create our own types with predefined list of possible values?

Tags: oop, typescript

I want my `Template.FOLDERS` to define a list of possible values (like an `enum`, but with strings). I want to be able to refer to these possible values to type my variables, so the compiler would warn me if I don't use one of the possible values.

Here is what I've done so far, but I think I got it wrong:

```
export class Template {
    public static FOLDERS: TemplateFolders = {
        CONTAINERS: 'containers',
        LAYOUTS: 'layouts',
        PARTIALS: 'partials',
        PAYMENT_METHODS: 'paymentMethods',
        MAIN: 'main'
    };
}

export interface TemplateFolders {
    CONTAINERS: string;
    LAYOUTS: string;
    PARTIALS: string;
    PAYMENT_METHODS: string;
    MAIN: string;
}
```

Then, in another class I use this:

```
protected TEMPLATE_FOLDER: string = Template.FOLDERS.MAIN;
```

But that's not what I want to do, I would like to type the `TEMPLATE_FOLDER` so that I can only set one of the predefined values.

How do I achieve that in TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## With an enum `TemplateFolder`

I suggest an [enumeration](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#basic-types-enum) or a [const enum](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/01/16/announcing-typescript-1-4.aspx) with a helper `toFolderName`:

```
export const enum TemplateFolder {
    Containers, Layouts, Partials, PaymentMethods, Main
}

var toFolderName = (function () {
    var names = ['containers', 'layouts', 'partials', 'paymentMethods', 'main'];
    return function (tf: TemplateFolder): string {
        return names[tf];
    };
})();

console.log(toFolderName(TemplateFolder.PaymentMethods)); // paymentMethods
```

## With a class `TemplateFolder`

```
class TemplateFolder {
    constructor(private name: string) {
    }
    public toString(): string {
        return this.name;
    }
}

var templateFolders = {
    CONTAINERS: new TemplateFolder('containers'),
    LAYOUTS: new TemplateFolder('layouts'),
    PARTIALS: new TemplateFolder('partials'),
    PAYMENT_METHODS: new TemplateFolder('paymentMethods'),
    MAIN: new TemplateFolder('main')
};

console.log(templateFolders.PAYMENT_METHODS); // paymentMethods
```

Of course, the variable `templateFolders` can be static in the class `Template`.

Comment: I didn't use `enum` because I couldn't find a way to set a value to each of them like: `enum Folders{ CONTAINERS: 'containers'}`, I need to set a value.

Comment: I suggest to use a function when the folder name is needed.

Comment: This looks more like a workaround, I'd prefer to use something proper. Another possibility could be to override the `TemplateFolder.toString()` function to automatically call the `toFolderName` function, just an idea.  Not sure it would work though, wondering if there isn't a better way.

Comment: A property in `TemplateFolder` is not an object but a string, there is no method `toString` to override.

Comment: Yeah... That's why I tried to use an object `{}` but didn't know how to type it.

Comment: My solution is not a workaround. `TemplateFolder` should be an `enum` because your need is an enumeration. With a `const enum`, you have good performance and a strong static control. When you have to convert a value to a string, you call the helper that converts it. It's just normal. Another good solution (more OOP) is to create a class `TemplateFolder` then instantiate it.

Comment: Do you have any example with a class? I've upvoted since it seems to be a good solution using `enum` but I'm interested with the OOP way as well. Thanks.

Comment: Done. Maybe useful if there are more properties or methods to put in `TemplateFolder`.

Comment: By the way, here is a post about `string enum` on Codeplex: https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1217

Comment: Hi, thanks for approving. I reject your edit because `enum` values should be named in PascalCase, following [the Handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#basic-types-enum). I removed the value `None` because it doesn't match with your question. Of course you do what you want in the code of your project, but the answer in StackOverflow aims to be read by other people. ;)

Comment: Okay, since there are constants it makes sense to write them in underscore notation instead of camelCase to me, plus I'm working with Java developpers so I'll follow my own conventions here, thanks for explaining :)